# Filtering an Array

Tags: php, arrays, class

I'm working on a website that displays properties. I have a huge XML feed in which I put into an array.

```
function search_results($department = '', $post_code = '', $min_price = '', $max_price = '', $type = '', $bedrooms = '') {
    foreach($this->xml->property as $property) {
        if($property->department == $department) {
            $this->properties[] = $property; 
        }
    }
    $this->filter_results();
}
```

this first filters the XML based on the department such as 'For Sale' or 'To Rent'. I want to now be able to search this array based on the variables I pass though the function. For example:

```
if($this->properties->regionID == $post_code) {
    $this->properties[] = $property;
}
```

But this doesn't work. This will be in a class called Results. How will I go about searching the array. I had a look at using array_filter(); but I couldn't get it working it would return Array() when I print_r it.

Does anyone know how to search/filter an array?

This is what the array looks like when I print_r:

> Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [propertyID] => 1 [branchID] => 1 [clientName] => Name [branchName] => Branch [department] => Lettings [referenceNumber] => 1 [addressName] => 4 [addressNumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [addressStreet] => address [address2] => address2 [address3] => address3 [address4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [addressPostcode] => postcode [country] => postcode [displayAddress] => address [propertyBedrooms] => 1 [propertyBathrooms] => 1 [propertyEnsuites] => 0 [propertyReceptionRooms] => 1 [propertyKitchens] => 1 [displayPropertyType] => Flat/Apartment [propertyType] => 2 [propertyStyle] => 16 [propertyAge] => 0 [floorArea] => 0.00 [floorAreaUnits] => sq ft [propertyFeature1] => Converted School House [propertyFeature2] => City Centre Location [propertyFeature3] => Modern Fittings [propertyFeature4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [propertyFeature5] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [propertyFeature6] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [propertyFeature7] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [propertyFeature8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [propertyFeature9] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [propertyFeature10] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [rent] => 525 [rentFrequency] => 1 [toLetPOA] => 0 [studentProperty] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [availability] => 2 [mainSummary] => summary. [fullDescription] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [dateLastModified] => 2014-05-02 [featuredProperty] => 0 [regionID] => 27 [latitude] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [longitude] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [flags] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [images] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [image] => Array ( [0] => image [1] => image [2] => image [3] => image [4] => image ) ))

Does anyone know how I would be able to search this query for example

```
$post_code = 43; $min_price = 300; $max_price = 500
```

and so on.

Comment: Possibly here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029050/how-to-remove-simplexmlelement-object-from-php-array

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, the logic seems good to me.
There is something though that might cause the issue.
On line 4 of your code, you have:

```
$this->properties[] = $property;
```

It means that you have an array of properties.

But then, you are trying to access the object directly:

```
if($this->properties->regionID == $post_code) {
    $this->properties[] = $property;
}
```

This looks strange to me. You are trying to see if an abject has the property you want, and then save the same object as it is an array.

So I guess, once you have built your `$this->properties` array, you just have to loop through it and apply your filters to return an array of properties with just what you are looking for:

```
foreach($this->properties as $singleProperty) 
{
    if($singleProperty->regionID == $post_code) 
    {
        $this->foundProperties[] = $singleProperty;
    }
}
```